# Will Google Firestore always write to the server immediately in a mobile app with frequent writes?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Is it possible to limit the speed at which Google Firestore pushes writes made in an app to the online database?

I'm investigating the feasibility of using Firestore to store a data stream from an IoT device via a mobile device/bluetooth.

The main concern is battery cost - receive a new data packet roughly two minutes, I'm concerned about the additional battery drain that an internet round-trip every two minutes, 24hrs a day, will cost.  I also would want to limit updates to wifi connections only.

It's not important for the data to be available online real-time. However it is possible for multiple sources to add to the same datastream in a 2-way sybc, (ie online DB and all devices have the merged data).

I'm currently handling that myself, but when I saw the offline capability of Datastore I hoped I could get all that functionality for free.

I know we can't directly control offline-mode in Firestore, but is there any way to prevent it from always and immediately pushing write changes online?

Comment: This isn't really a technical question and doesn't fit here in stackoverflow. This is fairly opinionated question. But if you have a more specific technical question then feel free to ask it. Depending on the structure of your app firestore or realtime database that is part of firebase could be a fit but would need more specific examples.

Comment: @Jonathan I would call this a "technical" question, but it's not terribly well researched. Frozenkiwi, you'll need to edit your question to ask something specific about some code you've written, especially this "batch" you're referring to, as well as other specific code you're using that you want to understand what it's doing and costing.

Comment: @DougStevenson that is more what I was trying to convey, but didn't say as well. frozenkiwi If you can give some more specific code would be glad to help

Comment: I removed the bit about the $ cost, as I was mistaken about batching being cheaper - the only other concern is about the battery life and whether or not it will update on data vs wifi, but these are much smaller concerns

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only technical question I can see here has to do with how batch writes operate, and more importantly, cost. Simply put, a batch write of 100 writes is the same as writing 100 writes individually. The function is not a way to avoid the write costs of firestore. Same goes for transactions. Same for editing a document (that's a write). If you really want to avoid those costs then you could store the values for the thirty minutes and let the client send the aggregated data in a single document. Though you mentioned you need data to be immediate so I'm not sure that's an option for you. Of course, this would be dependent on what one interprets "immediate" as based off the relative timespan. In my *opinion*, (I know those aren't really allowed here but it's kind of part of the question) if the data is stored over months/years, 30 minutes is fairly immediate. Either way, batch writes aren't quite the solution I think you're looking for.

EDIT: You've updated your question so I'll update my answer. You can do a local cache system and choose how you update however you wish. That's completely up to you and your own code. Writes aren't really automatic. So if you want to only send a data packet every hour then you'd send it at that time. You're likely going to want to do this in a transaction if multiple devices will write to the same stream so one doesn't overwrite the other if they're sending at the same time. Other than that I don't see firestore being a problem for you.

Comment: Duh - your right!  I was under the impression that batch writes were cheaper, but reading closer and it only says batches have "the same overhead as a single operation".

Comment: Updated my answer for your revised question. the TLDR version, I think you're good, just be sure to use transactions for your writes since you can have multiple clients writing to the same datastream.

Comment: Thanks a bunch for the updated answer.  One final question (and the key really): How?  Can Firestore supply all the functionality, or do I still need my own local SQLite DB as the staging area?

Comment: That is where you’ll need SQLite or some kind of local DB. Firestore doesn’t give access to its cache system.